# D3 render fill image refresh browser issue

Tags: d3.js, lwc

Seeing a weird issue where opening one page will load our network graph with filled circles of images, but jumping to another page will not display the circles. MOF two observations have been made:

1. Issue does not exist with Safari but only Chrome
2. Removing the image fill results in the circle being drawn

I've tried old and new versions of d3 v5, v6, v7. It's hard to test on jsfiddle because this is related to page changes inside Salesforce

The issue is not cache related as I've turned off cache and can see the images being downloaded in Chrome Dev Tools. Generally a refresh will fix the issue.
[Good Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij386.png)
[Bad Render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zL0E.png)